# Correct scope outside a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

My question is regarding the below code:

```
var z='1'; 
(function(){ 
   y='2'; 
   console.log(z+y); // '12'
})();
console.log(z+y); // '12'
```

How come 'y' is accessible outside the function's scope?

Comment: Because it is `global`...variables declared without `var` keyword are global variables..`var z='1'; 
(function(){ 
   var y='2'; 
   console.log(z+y);
})();
console.log(z+y);` will throw error _Uncaught ReferenceError: y is not defined_

Comment: with "var" like _var z='1'_ is local and without "var" like y='2' is global.

Comment: y is global variable..if u want to prevent then u should use var

Answer (score 3):

You declared `y` like this `y='2';`  By not putting the `var` keyword in front of it, the variable automatically becomes global.

Answer (score 0):

Key word without a var in front of it is declared as global variable.